# Name of this switch?

Tags: switches

[image]
[image]
[image]
Can some one tell me what this type of switch is? It seems kind of like a trigger in action.

Comment: I hereby name thee "Carl, the uncroppable"

Comment: Sure, but what is it *called*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's usually called a "detector switch". Digikey has them listed under "snap action, limit switches". There are many kinds, one similar type shown below.

[image]